# AJAX calls within MVC and Identity Server

Tags: ajax, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I have been playing with Thinktecture IdentityServer3 and am keen to use it as the product looks great. However, I don't fully understand how to accomplish my flow which is probably fairly common:

- Create Identity Server using Implicit flow
- Setup an MVC web site
- Setup a separate Web API

So far so good, as demonstrated in the examples on the site. I now wish to call the API using AJAX calls directly but for this i need an access token. It seems like a large overhead to have to route these through the MVC site itself (again, in the examples).

How can I accomplish this flow? Would it essentially blend the MVC and Javascript Client samples or is there a smoother way so the user only has to sign in once? Perhaps send the access token in a hidden field but then how would it renew?

Any help on understanding this would be great.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to come up with a solution which seems to work, not sure if it's best practice though...

- Expose a method on the MVC site at AJAX/AccessToken
- Method should be locked down with Authorize attribute to ensure the MVC part of the site is authenticating properly with IdentityServer
- Method returns the users Access Token which was generated through the above call via MVC controllers
- In JavaScript, simply use this endpoint to get an Access Token and then call the API manually
- The call to get the Access Token should be secure as its within the same domain/authentication model as the MVC site itself

I've put up a sample here for anyone interested:
[OIDC-Website](http://github.com/wdchris/OIDC-Website)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [form post client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MvcFormPostClient) to see the endpoints being called explicitly. You will need to hit the [token endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenEndpoint) to get your access token.

You should be able to use these endpoints in your AJAX calls, store the received claims and tokens in a cookie and take it from there.

Note that to renew the access token, you will also need to store the refresh token. The Implicit flow [does not allow](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication) for refresh tokens (you'll need to use the Authorization Code Flow or the Hybrid Flow).